# How to get the polygon coordinates from an open layers map using react

Tags: reactjs, openlayers, openlayers-6, openlayers-5

I'm trying to get the coordinate points from a drawn polygon in an Open layers map using `react`.

I'm having 2 problems

1. I cannot subscribed to the `drawend` cause when I do the function that I want trigger on that even does not gets trigered. When I uses another event, `click` for example my function runs?
2. I cannot get `event.feature.getGeometry()` to get the actual coordinates from my polygon. I works when I use points and the geometry of points, but **not** of polygons?

For example the below code works when I'm subscribing to `click` event on the Map and I can get the geometry for each point.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function useWatchOnMapDrawPolygon(mapRef) {
  const [polygonCoords, setPolygonCoords] = useState([]);

  const onDrawEnd = (event: any) => {
    const olMap = event.map;
    console.log("event.map inside useWatchOnMapDrawPolygon", olMap);
    console.log("olMap.getLayers", olMap.getLayers());

    olMap.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, (feature: any) => {
      const featureId = feature.getId();
      const extent = feature?.getGeometry()?.getExtent();

      console.log("featureId", featureId); // undefined
      console.log("extent", extent); // (4) [119175.69299028325, 175330.0603457574, 155684.03674028325, 201845.0525332574]0: 119175.692990283251: 175330.06034575742: 155684.036740283253: 201845.0525332574length: 4[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

      setPolygonCoords(extent); // (4) [119175.69299028325, 175330.0603457574, 155684.03674028325, 201845.0525332574]0: 119175.692990283251: 175330.06034575742: 155684.036740283253: 201845.0525332574length: 4[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!(mapRef && mapRef.current && mapRef.current.map)) {
      return;
    }

    mapRef.current.map.on("click", onDrawEnd);

    () => mapRef.current.map.un("click", onDrawEnd);
  }, [mapRef?.current?.map]);

  console.log("polygonCoords", polygonCoords);
  return polygonCoords;
}
```

But when I try to do the same  using the `drawend` event my function `onDrawEnd` does not run and `event.feature` comes back `undefined`.

**In the example below I'm tracking `click` event to force the `onDrawEnd` fn to run but then I do not get the data that I want which is coordinates from a polygon [[], [], ...etc]**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function useWatchOnMapDrawPolygon(mapRef) {
  const [polygonCoords, setPolygonCoords] = useState([]);

  const onDrawEnd = (event: any) => {
    const olMap = event.map;

    console.log("event.map inside useWatchOnMapDrawPolygon", olMap); // [NOTE]: This is the map object,
    console.log("olMap.getLayers", olMap.getLayers()); // [NOTE]: This is the layers object

    const polygonFeature = event.feature; // [Error]: Event does not have a feature property
    const polygonGeometry = polygonFeature.getGeometry(); // [ERROR]: Cannot read property 'getGeometry' of undefined
    const polygonCoordinates = polygonGeometry.getCoordinates();
    setPolygonCoords(polygonCoordinates); // [ERROR]
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!(mapRef && mapRef.current && mapRef.current.map)) {
      return;
    }

    mapRef.current.map.on("click", onDrawEnd);

    () => mapRef.current.map.un("click", onDrawEnd); // [NOTE]: I have tried `drawend` event, but it does not register it for some reason, and yet I can draw on the map. When I change to `click` or `moveend` it runs the onDrawEnd function.
  }, [mapRef?.current?.map]);

  console.log("polygonCoords", polygonCoords);
  return polygonCoords;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- The `drawend` event is on the interaction, not on the map. The map does not emit a `drawend` event.
- You are missing a `return` statement in `useEffect`, simply declaring a function is not enough, you have to return it.
- `forEachFeatureAtPixel` does not work if you click inside a hole of the polygon, make sure your polygons are solid. You can also check the `hitTolerance` parameter.

Also, I would advise against using `useEffect` for handling Openlayers maps as you will run into problems when React mounts and unmounts your components.

I don't know why the polygons